# How to get selected dropdown attribute in front end?

Tags: magento-1.9

I got drop down attribute in front end with all value (attribute id = silktype)

```
<li class="fields">
<label for="silktype"><?php echo $this->__('Silk Type'); ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
    <select class=" required-entry required-entry select" name="product[silktype]" id="silktype">
        <?php 
             $attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product','silktype');
             $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
             $attributeOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
             foreach($attributeOptions as $each){?>
               <option value="<?php echo $each[value]?>"><?php echo $each["label"]?></option><?php
             }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
</li>
```

Here i need selected attribute come first in option box. Please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with two method

**Method 1 : php**

```
$first = true;
foreach($attributeOptions as $each){?>
   <option value="<?php echo $each[value]?>"<?php echo ($first)?'selected="selected"' : ''?>><?php echo $each["label"]?></option>
   <?php
    $first = false;
}?>
```

**Method 2 : javascript**

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("silktype").selectedIndex = "0"; //Select first element
});
```

Comment: is it display rest of the attribute also?

Comment: you need to select the first value in dropdown right?

Comment: No i already stored some value in db that will come first rest of the thing come next